# Escuchar puerto LPT1 C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, windows

Eh logrado capturar el mensaje que se envía del TCP/IP ,con la clase `Listener` sin embargo me han pedido que escuche especialmente el Puerto LPT1 , ya que las impresoras de la empresa están conectadas vía Ethernet, y los mandan al puerto LPT1 de la impresora. Busco información y no encuentro nada , lo único que se me ocurre es instalar un emulador de impresora, pero no encuentro ninguno.

Las impresoras son `Intermec`.

El motivo de esto, es una aplicación (Que no tengo el código fuente) envía un archivo de imagen y con esto, se imprime una Etiqueta(Cantidad,Numero de parte,etc.), Quiero recibir esa información para poder utilizarla en una app que estoy desarrollando.

Este el código para recibir el mensaje TCP:

```
   class TCPIP
{

    TcpClient Client;
    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(9100);

    public void IniciarEspiar()
    {
        listener.Start();
    }


    public void Mandar()
    {

        Client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 9100);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Client.GetStream());
        writer.Write("Prueba para TCP/IP");
        writer.Flush();
    }

    public string Espiar()
    {

        try
        {
            string Data="";
            if ((listener.Pending() == true))
            {
                Client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(Client.GetStream());
                while ((Reader.Peek() > -1))
                {
                    Data += Convert.ToChar(Reader.Read()).ToString();
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Data))
                {
                    Attach.Escribir(Data);
                    return Data;

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { return ex.ToString(); }

        return "";

    }
}
```

Comment: Revisa esta [respuesta en SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30647048/4092887). Por curiosidad, ¿este proyecto va dirigido a algún sistema operativo en específico?  he encontrado [algunas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2137036/4092887) [fuentes](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cb34a005-0545-40df-b031-5e945ec0eb95/sending-info-to-lpt-port-from-c?forum=csharpgeneral) que pueden ser de utilidad, o investiga: `c# net use lpt1`.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave la cosa es que el OP entiendo que quiere leer del puerto serie, no escribir

Comment: @Pikoh, tienes razón, dejaré el comentario en todo caso. Gracias por la aclaración.

Answer (score 2):

En principio no hay nada "built-in" en .Net para leer directamente del puerto paralelo. Yo recuerdo haberlo hecho hace años para manejar paneles LCD, y necesité el uso de una libreria llamada [inpout32.dll](http://www.highrez.co.uk/Downloads/InpOut32/default.htm) que genera una especie de driver virtual que te permite acceder a los puertos a bajo nivel.

En esa url tienes enlace para la descarga del driver tanto para 32 como para 64bits, y en la descarga tienes códigos de ejemplo, espero que te sirvan.

Comment: Le echare un vistazo al link, Gracias.

Comment: Muy interesante esas librerias, me las guardo por si las necesito alguna vez.

Comment: @Veelicus yo las utilicé como dije para manejar paneles LCD y tambien para usar el puerto paralelo como emisor/receptor de señales digitales (en aquellos tiempos no habia cosas como Arduino) y funcionaba perfectamente. Pero hace años de ello :)